# mosquitto_pub Error: '-l' mode not available threading support has not been compiled in

Tags: macos, mqtt, mosquitto

When trying to publish a message to a topic using the mosquitto_pub `-l` flag, I get the error:

`Error: '-l' mode not available, threading support has not been compiled in.`

How can I correct this?

For reference mosquitto_pub is version 1.5.3, running on libmosquitto 1.5.3., and the command I am trying to run is:
`mosquitto_pub -h <hostname> -p <port> -t "<topic>" --cafile /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem -d -P "$(cat mqtt-token-pub.txt)" -u <username> -l`

*Note: it works if I use `-m "blah"` instead of `-l`*

Comment: How did you install the mosquitto tools? Did you compile mosquitto (and tools) yourself?

Comment: just with brew: `brew install mosquitto`

Comment: It sounds like who ever setup the homebrew instructions has got something wrong. Until it's fixed your only solution may be to build it yourself.

Comment: Hmm ok, fair enough, thanks for that.